# Internal error parsing svg file in android studio

Tags: android, svg, button

Использую ToggleButton в проекте, и хочу использовать SVG.
Далее жму `res -> New -> Vector Asset` выбираю `Locale file (SVG, PSD)` и указываю путь к SVG файлу и получаю ошибку. Не подскажете что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался также использовать конвертор `http://ozodrukh.github.io/Svg2MrVector/` и тогда выдает следующие ошибки при компиляции:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код ToggleButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_black_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_black_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: При парсинге пробовали переименовывать файл?

Comment: Гляньте тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895280/internal-error-parsing-svg-file-in-android-studio

Comment: Этот запрос я смотрел и, к сожалению, не смог в нём найти ответ. В итоге пришлось просто svg в png переделать и использовать...